# What are the ways to track the network traffic (HTTP/HTTPS) from Java source code?

Tags: java, android, network-traffic, network-monitoring

I would to track the network traffic generated from each method invocation. I first tried the time-sequenced method, i.e.

```
timeStamp();
task.foo();
timeStamp();
```

By using a traffic logger or interceptor to sort and match the traffic to each method call. However, there are some "interference" from other applications and I would repeatedly to test the network traffic tasks. I am think there are some existing network monitoring tools. Something like,

```
TrafficLog captureTraffic(Task task) {
     task.foo();
}
```

would be ideal that I may get the traffic log matching the method calling.

p.s. TrafficLog is expected to hold remote HTTP addresses/paths, IP addresses, local port usages, local thread ID and response time and optional for HTTP return code and body.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "track the network traffic". For example, what exactly does your theoretical `TrafficLog` hold?

Comment: For debugging apps, there is http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#network not sure if you can access your own stats from within your app though. But `TrafficStats.tagSocket` could potentialy allow you to figure out traffic for a certain method.

Comment: If your traffic tracker can inspect HTTP packets then you can easily filter them by checking the request URL for your application(s).